# Why can't an output be followed by an input and vice versa?

Tags: c, linux

From APUE

> When  a  ﬁle  is  opened  for  reading  and  writing  (the  plus  sign
>   in  the type),  two restrictions apply.
>
> • Output  cannot  be  directly  followed  by  input  without  an 
>   intervening fflush, fseek, fsetpos, or rewind.
>
> • Input  cannot  be  directly  followed  by  output  without  an 
>   intervening fseek, fsetpos, or rewind, or an input operation that
>   encounters an end of ﬁle.

Why "fseek, fsetpos, or rewind" in both cases?

Why "an input operation that encounters an end of ﬁle" in the second case?

Thanks.

A similar question for Linux API is [Can `read()` be directly followed by `write()` and `write()` by `read()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103562/can-read-be-directly-followed-by-write-and-write-by-read)

Comment: Why don't you read the whole discussion from APUE and not just part of it? Or, search for past discussions based on the keywords you learned?

Answer (score 4):

When working with a `FILE` stream, there is a single internal buffer used when either reading from or writing to the file.

When switching between reading and writing, that buffer **must** be cleared before switching modes, otherwise data loss could potentially occur.  Each of the operations mentioned above perform the required flushing of the buffer.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Do you mean the buffer in FILE object, or the buffer in kernel, or both? (2) In APUE or other references, I didn't find that "fseek, fsetpos, or rewind" and "an input operation that encounters an end of ﬁle" call fflush() or fsync(), or am I missing it?

Comment: @Tim I believe it's in the `FILE` object, since the library functions use the `open`, `read`, and `write` system calls internally.  I'm not familiar with APUE, but the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) does mention the above restrictions in section 7.21.5.3p7.

Comment: Do you mean it is sufficient to flush from FILE's buffer to kernel's buffer, and it doesn't matter whether flush from kernel's buffer to disk?

Comment: @Tim A `FILE` object performs its own buffering, so there are restrictions on how it's used.  The lower level file descriptors don't have that restriction.  How the kernel handles things is basically transparent to the user.

Comment: Why wasn't the C standard library also  made transparent in the same sense, so that I don't have to fflush() between output and input?

Comment: @Tim That's the way the standard is written.  It probably has to do with the level of detachment between kernel space and user space along with the kernel's own threads.

Comment: @Tim I believe the Standard was written that way to reflect longstanding practice.  The legacy implementations all worked that way, and no one wanted the Standard to invalidate them all.

Comment: @Tim Also, there's a sense that the restriction isn't onerous.  Very few programs seem to need to read, then switch to writing at the same spot, or vice versa.  Most random-access programs, that both read then write, tend to naturally have to seek to a new spot when changing from reading to writing, anyway.

Comment: Thanks. @dbush For Linux API, can `read()` be directly followed by `write()` and `write()` by `read()`? If yes, why is such a difference between Linux API and C library IO API?

Comment: @dbush  7.21.5.3p7 in [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) doesn't say file positioning functions internally flush output to device or clear input cache. I was wondering why the file positioning functions (if not `fflush`) should be called  between output and input?

Answer (score 0):

> the C standard doesn't say file positioning functions internally flush output to device or clear input cache.

The Standard indeed hasn't mentioned about the detail of somewhat internal buffering mechanism, because it varies from OS to OS; that is, implementation dependent. Thus, the standard is not responsible for defining it.

> I was wondering why the file positioning functions (if not fflush) should be called between output and input?

Since the behaviour is implementation dependent, for some OS (e.g. Ubuntu), interestingly, there is no need for us to call `fflush()`,`fseek()` explicitly, while others(e.g. macOS) strictly needs.

For the sake of a concrete description, I've run some tests on two OS:

1. macOS Big Sur (Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0)
2. Ubuntu 14 (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-142-generic)

Taking an example of "replace the 5th character in the file", and assume that the file content is

```sh
1234_6789
```

and the program is as followes:

```c
show_file_content();

getc(fp);
getc(fp);
getc(fp);
getc(fp);

/* this line is indispensable for macos, but NOT for ubuntu */
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_CUR);

putc('5', fp);

printf("->");

show_file_content();
```

the above program's output is (no matter running on macOS or Ubuntu):

```sh
1234_6789->123456789
```

But, if we comment the line of `fseek`, things are different; the outputs are...
macOS:

```sh
1234_6789->1234_67895
```

Ubuntu:

```sh
1234_6789->123456789
```

You can try this test on other different OSes. The comparison between two different Unix-based OSes suffices to understand the APUE's statement.