# Can `read()` be directly followed by `write()` and `write()` by `read()`?

Tags: c, linux, io

[In the C standard library, an output can't be followed by an input and vice versa.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068914/why-cant-an-output-be-followed-by-an-input-and-vice-versa)

For Linux API, can `read()` be directly followed by `write()` and `write()` by `read()`? If yes, why is such a difference between Linux API and C library IO API?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate of the other question. The reason for the restriction with `FILE` is the internal buffer that has to be managed correctly. File descriptors are just integers; they have no buffer attached.

Answer (score 2):

Your other question (linked) lacks a bit of context. When it says "When a ﬁle is opened for reading and writing (the plus sign in the type), two restrictions apply.", it refers to the files opened and operated on using `FILE *` streams (e.g., `fopen`, `fscanf`, `fprintf`, etc) - not the ones operated on file descriptors (e.g., `open`, `read`, `write`, etc).

Only `FILE *` streams typically have an associated stdio buffers; file descriptors don't have any associated buffers (there could be other buffers at lower levels such as in kernel, disk controllers, etc - but that's something you usually don't have to worry about). So `read(2)` and `write(2)` don't buffer anything (no stdio buffers). So they don't have such I/O order restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

To recap the other answer, when using stdio, you're working with a buffer which is not the actual file.  That buffer must be copied from the actual file (via the OS `read` call) if you're reading, and it must be copied to the actual file (via the OS `write` call) if you're writing.  If you switch too hastily from, say, writing to reading, the stdio code doesn't realize that it has to flush the written buffer and reload the buffer for reading.

When using the `read` and `write` system calls, on the other hand, things are different.  For one thing, you might be reading and writing a device (like a serial port, or TCP network stream), in which case there's obviously no problem jumping back and for the between reading and writing.

But even if you're using the `read` and `write` system calls to read and write a file, you're accessing the file -- or at least, the OS's notion of the file -- directly.  None of the concerns mentioned for stdio buffers apply.

(Ironically, the OS is typically working with a buffered copy of one or more of the file's blocks, also.  But the implementation is completely different, and doesn't end up having any problems if you switch back and forth between reading and writing.)

As explained in the other answer, the stdio routines *could* have been written to support interleaved i/o, but they weren't, in the interests of simplicity and efficiency.

Why is it this way?  One other piece of the puzzle is that, in the early days of C and Unix, system calls were extremely expensive.  A system call might take 10 or 100 times longer than an ordinary function call.  So there was a real premium placed on avoiding unnecessary system calls, and the stdio library was a big part of this.  It takes one `read` call to fill the buffer, and then you can make lots of little calls to fetch individual (or small numbers of) characters out of the buffer, without incurring any more overhead.  Similarly, while writing, you can make lots of little calls to write small numbers of characters, and then there's just one expensive `write` call to flush the buffer.  Having stdio support interleaved reads and writes -- which was not seen as an important use case -- would have required more system calls, or more tests, or more code (or all three), and in general would have been more expensive than it was worth.

(Today, system calls are much less inefficient, so if C and Unix were being designed from scratch today, the distinction between the `read` and `write` system calls versus the stdio input and output calls might have worked out rather differently.)