# Do the file positioning functions internally flush output to device and clear input cache?

Tags: c, linux, io

From  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52068965/156458

> When switching between reading and writing, that buffer must be cleared before switching modes, otherwise data loss could potentially occur. Each of **the operations** mentioned above perform the required flushing of the buffer.

"the operations" include fseek, fsetpos, and rewind.

Do the file positioning functions internally flush output to device and clear input cache?
[7.21.5.3p7 in the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) doesn't say it. I don't find it in the manpages of the file positioning functions either.

If not, Why should the file positioning functions (if not `fflush`)  be called between output and input?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the update (`+`) mode for opening a file contains this detail:

> When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the
>   above list of `mode` argument values), both input and output may be performed on the
>   associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
>   intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`,
>   `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an
>   intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters endof-file.

So while the descriptions of those functions don't explicitly mention that they flush the buffer, this clause implies it. But it's only required when the update mode is used.